# how to exce middleware , when the laravel exception

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel5.5 for a web program. But when the program is exception, the middleware don't work.

what  should i do for it?

my middleware code is list:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;


class ApiException
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $env = config('app.env');
        $statusCode = $response->getSatusCode();
        if ($statusCode >= 500 && $env != 'dev') {
            $response->setContent(['error' => 'Internal Server Error']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

thank you help me !

Comment: *the middleware don't work* is an absolutely useless problem description. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post. You need to be clear when describing the problem (the behavior you expect and what you're getting instead, including any error messages), and ask a **specific question**. If you're not sure why *dont work* is not useful, call your auto repair shop and say *My car don't work. How long will it take to fix it and what will it cost?* and see if they can answer based on that problem description.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do that in `Middlewares`. You can control exceptions in your `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In middleware can't but in Exception/Handler can..

anytime the exception occurred.. it not entered the middleware, it entered Exception/Handler.php..

in render method

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
        if ($exception->getCode() >= 500 ||) {
            //return redirect()->route(); do something here
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```